# tidyverse conflict in RStudio Cloud

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio-server, gtsummary

I am transferring my work from `Rstudio` to `RStudio Cloud`. I ran a code similar to this basic code using the `gtsummary` package.

```
install.packages(c("tidyverse","gtsummary"))
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
Table1 <- cars %>% tbl_summary()
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `tbl_stats`. 
x invalid multibyte string, element 1 ℹ Input `tbl_stats` is `pmap(...)`. 
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I don't get any error messages when I run it using `reprex()`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
Table1 <- cars %>% tbl_summary()

<sup>Created on 2021-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>
```

However, when I run the same code alone it gives me the following in the console:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `tbl_stats`.
x invalid multibyte string, element 1
ℹ Input `tbl_stats` is `pmap(...)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` input `tbl_stats`.
ℹ input string 1 is invalid in this locale
ℹ Input `tbl_stats` is `pmap(...)`.
```

I think it has to do with `dplyr`. When I restart Rstudio and re-install the package and call it. I get the following under `tidyverse_conflicts()` !!

```
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
```

Comment: FYI, I just added this code to an RStudio Cloud project and it ran without any issues....

Comment: Can you show us the output when you add this code to a proper reprex using `reprex::reprex()`

Comment: Hi @DanielD.Sjoberg, I must say now. I don't think it has to do with `gtsummary`. It's probably a problem when calling `dplyr`. I don't know what's causing it yet through. I updated the question. Thank you for the fast response.